# Convert PDE to a set of ODEs (without assuming separated form)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have encountered the following problem. Consider a PDE:

$$
\begin{align}
&\left( -\frac{\partial Z}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial Y}{\partial z}  \right)\frac{\partial  u}{\partial x} + \left( \frac{\partial X}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial Z}{\partial x}  \right)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \left( \frac{\partial Y}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial X}{\partial y}  \right)\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} = \\\\
&= X\left( \frac{\partial Z}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial Y}{\partial z}  \right) + Y \left( \frac{\partial X}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial Z}{\partial x}  \right) + Z\left( \frac{\partial Y}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial X}{\partial y}  \right)
\end{align}
$$

Which for short be written as:
$$\tag{1}
\begin{align}
&P\frac{\partial  u}{\partial x} + Q\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + R\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} &= T
\end{align}
$$

Assume that $P,Q,R,T$ are all nonzero functions of $x,y,z$. The text that I am reading goes on to say that to find a solution of the PDE, one converts it to a set of ODEs which are:

$$\tag{2}
\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{P} = \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{Q} = \frac{\mathrm{d} z}{R} = \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{T}
$$

My primary issue is that I do not know, what this last equation is supposed to be, and how it is an ODE. One idea that came to mind is if one plays with the derivative as if it was a fraction and says: since the functions $X,Y,Z$ have to satisfy the PDE for all $x,y,z$ (from some domain), specifically, it has to be valid in the case when we hold $x,y$ constant, which leads to:

$$\tag{3}
\frac{T}{R} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} = \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{\mathrm{d} z}
$$

which by the dirty fraction game "becomes":
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{R} = \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{T}
$$
analogously the "game" continues, hold $x,z$ constant:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{Q} = \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{T}
$$

and so forth. But this is just a guess to somehow understand what is going on. Can someone explain how one gets (2) from (1). And if it really is by an argument close to what I wrote in (3), is this a general procedure to get ODEs from PDEs (other than assuming separated from $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$) and are there any other conditions than for $P,Q,R,T$ be non-zero?

Comment: It looks like the methods of characteristics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics